# how to take thread dump in jboss when the server is down?

Tags: jboss5.x

How to take thread dump when the server is down.
i am able to get thread dump when the server is running.
but i want to take thread dump when the server is down to analyze the cause for the server why it is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get dump when the server is down. You have to study log file. 
If your sever often  crashes, I recomend to connect  to the running server using the Java VisualVM or other monitoring tool in order to find out the cause.